# Getting SUM of MySQL table data when there is floating point numbers

Tags: mysql

I an using  MySQL database and I have a table called fertilizer_storage which is using both plus and minus values. It has 4 columns uria,TSP,MOP and TDM

I am using double as data type and getting sum of each column using follwing syntax,

```
SELECT SUM(uria),SUM(TSP),SUM(MOP),SUM(TDM) FROM `fertilizer_storage` WHERE `branch_ID`=1
```

The problem is for some columns I get unwanted floating points of 15 while all columns are containing numbers up to 4 floating points.

```
7.666900000000002
7.666900000000002
9.6109
9.9924
```

when I changed numbers in first two columns as other two it gives the correct answer. what should I do to correct this.

Comment: Are you aware that doubles and floats are by definition not 100% correct? They are an approximation. That is also probably why you get the weird results. I'd recommend changing the data type to a decimal for example and then making sure it is always accurate until 4 characters behind the comma.

Comment: I agree. It's unlikely to me that you would want DOUBLE of FLOAT for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ROUND(X, D)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round):

> Rounds the argument X to D decimal places. The rounding algorithm
>   depends on the data type of X. D defaults to 0 if not specified. D can
>   be negative to cause D digits left of the decimal point of the value X
>   to become zero.

```
SELECT Round(Sum(uria), 4), 
       Round(Sum(tsp), 4), 
       Round(Sum(mop), 4), 
       Round(Sum(tdm), 4) 
FROM   `fertilizer_storage` 
WHERE  `branch_id` = 1
```

[**See it in action**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85cd4/3)

Comment: Glad it works. You can accept answer, which shall help others in future.